# Mail has stopped working on Centos since instlling MailScanner

Tags: centos, postfix, sendmail, mailscanner

I have a VPS which I rent and it is running Centos 6. The VPS has ZPanel installed which is used to host some websites and emails.

I have just installed Mailscanner and now, I have noticed that emails don't seem to be working.
I looked at my mail queue and I found that they emails are just stuck in the queue.

I have checked to see if MailScanner is running and this is what I found:

> incoming sendmail: head: cannot open '/var/run/sendmail.in.pid

[image: Error on Server]

What can I do to get this working?

FYI: This is a link to the tutorial which I followed to try to install MailScanner:

> http://xmodulo.com/mailscanner-clam-antivirus-spamassassin-centos.html

Comment: Just to confirm, does your MailScanner.conf explicitly reference Postfix (MTA = postfix)? It sounds like it's still trying to use Sendmail. Check out: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1053325

Comment: That is exactly what the issue was. It now works.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MailScanner supports multiple MTAs and in this case, it sounds like the configuration file (MailScanner.conf) is configured to use sendmail instead of postfix.

As per the prior guide you referenced, it should have something like this:

```
%org-name% = test CentOS Mail Server
%org-long-name% = ORGFULLNAME
%web-site% = ORG WEBSITE

Run As User = postfix
Run As Group = postfix
MTA = postfix
```

Can you please verify that the param `MTA = postfix` is present? Perhaps it's set to `sendmail` by accident?